# Why a correct SQL query fails silently when using PyMySQL but succedes using mySQL workBench?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, pymysql, executemany

I am attempting to `INSERT INTO` using a correct SQL query and Python's PyMySQL package. I know it is correct since the same query, when doing a Copy/Paste into mySQL workbench, inserts it all right!

However, using Python's pymysql package and cursor.executemany() it fails silently, and returns as `rowcount` minus 1 (-1).

Here is the piece of code:

```py
ins_query = "REPLACE INTO `household`.`expenses`(`ID`,`Date`,`Sum`,`Class`,`Description`,`Necessity`) VALUES (NULL,'2021-12-23', 800, 'Groceries','Test-3',NULL )"

# ------------------------------
        cursor = self.conn.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.executemany(ins_query)
        except pymysql.Error as e:
            print("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))
            return  False
        self.conn.commit()
        return cursor.rowcount
```

Comment: Please can you [edit] the question to include the _complete_ error traceback.

Comment: Dear @snakecharmerb,
There is no exception that was raised. The call to `executemany` just returned -1 and _didn't_ changed the DB!

Comment: Well, I changed from `executemany()` to `execute()` and since there is just a single record to insert, it worked correctly, inserted a record into the DB table and returned one (1) as the `cursor.rowcount` result.
I wonder why `executemany` with just one record is not legal...?

Comment: If I try calling `executemany` with just a query string I get `TypeError: Cursor.executemany() missing 1 required positional argument: 'args'`.  For what you appear to be doing - passing an already complete sql statement - just use `execute`.

Comment: When you say "... with just a query string ..." do you mean that one needs to compile a query without the "VALUES ( --- args ---)" and separate the args into a tuple-of-tuples variable that is fed as a second positional argument to the `executemany` method?
Can you give an example? Thanks!

Comment: For a single set of values `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO tbl (c1, c2) VALUES (%s, %s""", (v1, v2))`; for multiple values for the same statement `cursor.executemany("""INSERT INTO tbl (c1, c2) VALUES (%s, %s""", [(v1, v2), (v3, v4)..])`

Comment: Thanks! I will try that and report. Good night!

Comment: The pymysql docs aren't very extensive, but you can read [PEP-249](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) to understand how a generic, conformant, Python database connector works.